# excel vba - custom formula for Contains()

Tags: vba, excel, scripting

If i had a column like:

```
ColumnA
-------
NUMBER
VARCHAR(50 BYTE)
TIMESTAMP
```

I'm looking for a vba function that would work like so:

contains("string to search for", cell to search it in)
ie. =contains("VARCHAR",A2)
and if the cell does contain it (anywhere in the cell - doesn't have to start or end the cell) then populate the cell (that uses the function) with "T" else "F".

so in my example:

```
ColumnB
-------
F
T
F
```

Also could I then use this function inside other VBA code like so:

```
If Len(A2) > 10 and contains("CHAR",A2) Then
 //do stuff
End If
```

If they have to be separate functions (to use in cells returning "T"/"F" and to use in other VBA code), please provide both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want VBA's `InStr`

For example in a module;

```
Public Function Contains(Text As String, Cell As Range) As String
   If InStr(1, Cell.Value, Text, vbTextCompare) Then '//case insensitive
       Contains = "T"
   Else
       Contains = "F"
   End If
End Function
```

Enables `=Contains("blah", A1)` in a worksheet

Comment: when i try it on a worksheet it comes up with: #NAME? in the cell

Comment: If I put that code in a module (must be a module) then in A1 put `"AWA"` if I enter `=contains("W",A1)` into B2 it becomes `T`

Comment: ah, yes in a module it works. I had only ever had code in sheets.

Comment: actually, how would i then use the Contains function in other vba code? like If Len(A2) > 10 and contains("CHAR",A2) Then....

Comment: with instr() again; `If Len(Range("A1").Value) > 20 And InStr(1, Range("A1").Value, "CHAR", vbTextCompare) Then ...`